# BeautifulSoup - find class AND exclude another class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the time range from a source code of a page, using BeautifulSoup in python.

The line I'm trying to parse look like this

```
<span class="experience-date-locale"><time>June 2010</time> – <time>August 2010</time> (3 months)<span class="locality">New York</span></span>

<span class="experience-date-locale"><time>October 2015</time> – Present (7 months)</span>

<span class="experience-date-locale"><time>May 2010</time> – <time>October 2011</time> (6 months)</span>
```

and I dont know how to get it right

This line i tried didnt work becuase sometime I also have 'locality' class...

```
soup.find('span', {'class': 'experience-date-locale'}).text
```

this doesn't work too becuase I miss the 'present' part

```
soup.find('span', {'class': 'experience-date-locale'}).findAll('time').text
```

how can I exclude the part of the location and get only the time?

The result should be :

```
June 2010 - August 2010 (3 months)

October 2015 - present (7 months)

May 2010 - October 2011 (6 month)
```

Comment: What is the result of the second snippet?

Comment: @LutzHorn it throws AttributeError. but it actually wont really help eitherway cause it doesnt solve the problem if the date has "present"

Comment: Does any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to remove the extra `<span>` tag when it's there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span class="experience-date-locale"><time>June 2010</time> – <time>August 2010</time> (3 months)<span class="locality">New York</span></span>
<span class="experience-date-locale"><time>October 2015</time> – Present (7 months)</span>
<span class="experience-date-locale"><time>May 2010</time> – <time>October 2011</time> (6 months)</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for e in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'experience-date-locale'}):
    if e.span:
        _ = e.span.extract()
    print(e.text)
```

**Output**

```
June 2010 – August 2010 (3 months)
October 2015 – Present (7 months)
May 2010 – October 2011 (6 months)
```

This gives the output that you want, however, it does alter the document tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for span in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "experience-date-locale"}):
    for child in span.contents:
        if isinstance(child, bs4.element.Tag) and child.name == "time":
            print(child.text, end='')
        elif isinstance(child, bs4.element.NavigableString):
            print(child, end='')
    print()
```

Output:

```
June 2010 – August 2010 (3 months)
October 2015 – Present (7 months)
May 2010 – October 2011 (6 months)
```